# How Can I Add New Value On Column Database /PYTHON

Tags: python, database, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("Demo.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
query = "UPDATE Table set demoName = %s Where demoId = %s"
cursor.execute(query,("demoName",1)
con.commit()
```

This method is not work. 
I want to keep the current values ​​in the column and add more values ​​to those values. I can do that with what code. Updating doesn't work here.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE` sql command is to update existing rows. Use the `INSERT` sql command to create new rows.

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("Demo.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
query = "INSERT INTO Table (demoName, demoId) VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(query,("demoName",1)
con.commit()
```

Python official sqlite3 documentation suggests the following links for learning sql:

> - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/ - Tutorial, reference and examples for learning SQL syntax.
> - https://www.sqlite.org - The SQLite web page; the documentation describes the syntax and the available data types for the supported SQL dialect.

Comment: But I don't want to create a new row. I want to add the end of a row that is already ready.

Comment: @AdilHaydar I don't understand what you mean. Each row is composed by one value for each field. You want to add more text to your `demoName` column? Maybe you should edit the question and add example of your database contents and how you want your results to be

Comment: Think like file methods. Update, like "w" method on file. But I want to add something like "a" method in the file to the end of a filled row in the database.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column_name = column_name + ?`